# Is it possible to define n-point functions in classical field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I want to show that n-point functions in classical field theory (say phi fourth theory) are given by tree diagrams, but I do not know how to proceed without using dZ/dJdJdJ which seems to be valid only for quantum theory.

Comment: What about the standard definition $\langle \phi(x_1)\dots\phi(x_n)\rangle$ doesn't work? What you've written there is just how they are *computed* in the path integral formalism.

Comment: Yes. That's the reason why I am asking. I do not know how $$\langle \phi(x_1)\cdots \phi(x_n)\rangle$$ is defined in classical theory.

Answer (score 1):

In quantum theory,
$$ Z[J] = \int D \varphi \exp \left( i \, S[\varphi] + \int d^4 x \, J(x) \, \varphi(x) \right). $$

The corresponding classical quantity (in the stationary phase approximation) is given by
$$ Z_c [J] = \exp \left( i \, S[\varphi_0] + \int d^4 x \, J(x) \, \varphi_0(x) \right), $$

where $\varphi_0(x)$ is the solution of the classical equations of motion.

The definition of the $n$-point correlation functions is straightforward, the only difference being that we plug $Z_c$ instead of $Z$.

These correspond to tree graphs (without closed loops).